# How to write $('input').after(" ") in YUI or pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

Just what it says,

Want to have this

```
$('input').after(" ");
```

in YUI, or if not possible in YUI then in pure javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also possible as a one-liner in YUI, if that's what you're using:

```
Y.all('input').insert(' ','after');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h87zP/

Comment: Thanks Barny, that's exactly what i was looking for. Although it does not have the desired effect I was after. jquery (http://jsfiddle.net/C3sHf/1/) , YUI (http://jsfiddle.net/9eTrP/) The output using jquery is different from YUI. Thanks anyways, you answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

Try following (http://jsfiddle.net/RCUcU/)

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("input");
var text = "some text";
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(textNode, node)
}
```

You will create text node (it isn't html element)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode